# Textbox which accepts only numbers in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

```js
methods: {
    acceptNumber() {
      var x = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      this.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ')' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    }
```

```html
<input class="input-section label-set"
       type="text"
       v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
       :class="{'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile)}"
       placeholder="Enter your mobile number"
       :maxlength="maxmobile" v-model="value"
       @input="acceptNumber"
/>

<div v-if="!$v.mobile.minLength"
     class="invalid-feedback"
>Kindly check phone {{ $v.mobile.$params.maxLength.min }} number.</div>
```

For the above code in the textbox, I  need to accept only numbers. and i need change the pattern of number to something like ""4356754356""(schould display numbers only in series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need textbox [input] which accepts only numbers for the code. (phone number which accepts only numbers not characters).

So to accept only numeric characters, the `acceptNumber()` method's rather complicated string manipulation needs to be modified.

A good way to know what's happening with a complex string manipulation is to break it down into sections.

This code:

```js
var x =this.value.replace(/\D/g,'').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
this.value=!x[2]?x[1]:'('+x[1]+')'+x[2]+(x[3]?'-'+x[3]:'');
```

Can be broken down into simple steps:

```js
let thisValue = '(123) 456-7890';

let x = thisValue.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(`x: "${x}"`);
// x: "1234567890"

x = x.match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
console.log('x.match:', JSON.stringify(x));
// x.match: ["1234567890","123","456","7890"]

thisValue = !x[2]
  ? x[1]
  :'(' + x[1] + ')' + x[2] +
    (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
console.log(`thisValue: "${thisValue}"`);
// thisValue: "(123)456-7890"
```

Notice that the first item of the `x` array is just the phone digits, which is what the OP is seeking:

```js
this.value = x[0];  // "1234567890"
```

Here is a minimal version of the original code with the above change. Note that it filters out all non-numeric characters as they are typed.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: '',
    maxmobile: 10
  },
  methods: {
    acceptNumber() {
      const x = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      console.log('this.value:', this.value, 'x:', x);
      this.value = x;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Enter your mobile number" :maxlength="maxmobile" v-model="value" @input="acceptNumber" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for info. Sorry i think there is miscommunication, What i mean is, I need textbox which accepts only numbers for the code. (phone number which accepts only numbers not characters).

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay Please edit your question above to make clear what you are asking for. Also, do you want to filter out non-numeric characters from the input while the user is typing? This may help: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sure. I mean when user is typing something in textbox, it should only accepts numbers only.(for example if try to enter characters or special characters in textbox, it should not take those values.)

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay "I need textbox [input] which accepts only numbers for the code" — This is what I have produced for you in my answer. See the working code snippet. Also, don't just answer with a comment. Clarify your question by editing it above.

Answer (score 2):

for only number input add this on tag `onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'`
it works for me

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```